# how to replace string with actual url

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
This is your <link>Here</link>
```

I want to replace `link` tag with actual link so my string looks like

```
This is your <a href='URL'>Here</a>
```

I was trying `String.Replace`,  but couldn't achieve the expected output. How can I replace it?

Comment: can you show me how? cant understand from your code

Comment: i really cannot understand what have you posted. Isnt my question different.

Comment: Can you have more that one `<link>` tag in your string?

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze you can see that i have 2

Comment: @MethodMan i dont think you have understood question?

Comment: I assume your second tag should be a closing `</link>` tag for the first (and only) `<link>` tag. Is it not the case?

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze yes updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to capture and replace:

```
var url = "www.google.com";
var oldString = "<link>Here</link>";   

// Named regex capturing group
var capturePattern = "(<link>)(?<label>.*)(</link>)";

// Replace pattern that changes link tag to a tag and inserts your label
var replacePattern = "<a href='" + url + "'>${label}</a>";

var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, capturePattern, replacePattern,
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You might want to include `[ ]*` constructs to you capture pattern to avoid extra spaces. For example this capture pattern will allow spaces in you `link` tags and will trim the captured label:

```
var capturePattern = "<[ ]*link[ ]*>[ ]*(?<label>.*)[ ]*<[ ]*/[ ]*link[ ]*>";
```